# Linear address translation when using pae paging

Tags: c, x86, paging, kvm, page-tables

I'm trying to walk through (and print) process paging structures from the hypervisor level. The guest I'm running is 32bits OS (ubuntu 12.04) that uses PAE (physical address extensions) paging.

The following picture from intel manual shows the details of the different structures when using PAE paging

[image: PAE = 1]

I'm confused about how to use these information:

To access the different PDPTEs: should I use `CR3 + i` (including the ignored bits) or shift right CR3 by 4 then add an offset `(CR3 >> 4) + i` ?

Similarly for address of page directory from PDPTEs, I understand that I should exclude the flags from the entry and its 40 bits (12:51). However, I get only 0ed PDEs (I used `CR3 + i`) for all PDPTEs ...
I used `kvm_read_guest(vcpu->kvm, cr3 + i, &pdpte, 8)` to read PDPTEs and `kvm_read_guest(vcpu->kvm, (pdpte >> 12) + i, &pde, 8)` to read PDEs from PDPTEs

If anyone has any explanation for this I would be very thankful :)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think what you want is `kvm_read_guest(vcpu->kvm, (cr3 & VALID_CR3_BITS_MASK)  + i * 8, &pdpte, 8)` where `VALID_CR3_BITS_MASK==0xfffffff0`(not tested).

Comment: I see,
So, I should zero the flags of the entries and not remove them from the physical address ?

Comment: Yes AFAIR if you mask (I think the mask I provided above might be wrong so double check it) out the ignored/ressrved bits of CR3 and add 8 (size of each PDPT entry) * i (index into PDPT) you should get the physical address of the PDPTE(ntry).

Comment: Thanks, and for PDEs and PTEs should I just mask the (12 bits) flags (zero them) ? or shift them and preserve only the base addresses ? It's not yet very clear to me.

Comment: Just mask the ignored/reserved bits. The physical addresses contained in the tables are page aligned.

Comment: Yes, everything works fine now and I can see what I want from the hypervisor :)